# How to automatically remove older log files in log4j2

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, lombok

I am using log4j2 for logging in my application, the log rotation is happening properly but i want the older log files to be deleted automatically once they meet a condition(like 15days old or max 100files).

My log4j2.xml file

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">/var/log/my-application</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                 fileName="${log-path}/xyz.log"
                 filePattern="${log-path}/xyz-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %level [%file:%line] %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="40">
            <Delete basePath="${log-path}" maxDepth="2">
                <IfFileName glob="*/xyz-*.log">
                    <IfLastModified age="1d">
                        <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="4"/>
                    </IfLastModified>
                </IfFileName>
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

But it's not removing the old log files so i have used DefaultRolloverStrategy to delete the files but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated on how to remove these old logs.

Comment: Have the same problem. Do you have meanwhile found a solution?

Comment: The problem I had was that the *.gz files were located in further nested sub-folders but the glob file pattern was wrong. Instead of "*/app-*.log.gz" I had to write "\*/**/app-*.log.gz"